# How to search downwards a column for a value based on whether another column is NA or not?

Tags: r

This post is similar to another post where the direction was to look upwards on the column: [How to search upwards a column for a value based on whether another column is NA or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72026477/how-to-search-upwards-a-column-for-a-value-based-on-whether-another-column-is-na/72027016?noredirect=1#comment127269736_72027016)

This time I need to look downwards on the first and second entry where value is not NA.

Again, using a simple shift will not work here.

**EDIT: Added grouping variable and the possibility of both TYPE and VALUE NOT NA**

```
dtihave = data.table(id = c(rep(1,9)),
                     date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-03", "2020-04-02", "2020-05-09", "2020-06-10", "2020-07-18", "2020-08-23", "2020-09-09")),
                     type = c(1,1,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,1),
                     value = c(7,NA,6,8,15,NA,5,9,NA))
> dtihave
   id       date type value
1:  1 2020-01-01    1     7
2:  1 2020-02-01    1    NA
3:  1 2020-03-03    1     6
4:  1 2020-04-02   NA     8
5:  1 2020-05-09    1    15
6:  1 2020-06-10    1    NA
7:  1 2020-07-18   NA     5
8:  1 2020-08-23   NA     9
9:  1 2020-09-09    1    NA
```

```
dtiwant2 =  data.table(id = c(rep(1,9)),
                       date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-03", "2020-04-02", "2020-05-09", "2020-06-10", "2020-07-18", "2020-08-23", "2020-09-09")),
                       type = c(1,1,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,1),
                       value = c(7,NA,6,8,15,NA,5,9,NA),
                       iwantdateonedown = c(as.Date("2020-03-03"), as.Date("2020-03-03"), as.Date("2020-04-02"), NA, as.Date("2020-07-18"), as.Date("2020-07-18"), NA,NA,NA),
                       iwantvalueonedown = c(6,6,8,NA,5,5,NA,NA,NA),
                       iwantdatetwodown = c(as.Date("2020-04-02"), as.Date("2020-04-02"), as.Date("2020-05-09"), NA, as.Date("2020-8-23"), as.Date("2020-08-23"), NA,NA,NA),
                       iwantvaluetwodown = c(8,8,15,NA,9,9,NA,NA,NA))

> dtiwant2 
   id       date type value iwantdateonedown iwantvalueonedown iwantdatetwodown iwantvaluetwodown
1:  1 2020-01-01    1     7       2020-03-03                 6       2020-04-02                 8
2:  1 2020-02-01    1    NA       2020-03-03                 6       2020-04-02                 8
3:  1 2020-03-03    1     6       2020-04-02                 8       2020-05-09                15
4:  1 2020-04-02   NA     8             <NA>                NA             <NA>                NA
5:  1 2020-05-09    1    15       2020-07-18                 5       2020-08-23                 9
6:  1 2020-06-10    1    NA       2020-07-18                 5       2020-08-23                 9
7:  1 2020-07-18   NA     5             <NA>                NA             <NA>                NA
8:  1 2020-08-23   NA     9             <NA>                NA             <NA>                NA
9:  1 2020-09-09    1    NA             <NA>                NA             <NA>                NA
```

Current solution

```
dtihave %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate( value = replace(value, 1, NA),
          val_na = !is.na(value), idx=na_if(val_na * row_number(), 0),
          idx = nafill(idx, 'nocb'), idx = idx * NA^val_na,
          idx1 = row_number() *na_if(val_na & lag(val_na), 0),
          idx1 = nafill(idx1, 'nocb') * NA ^val_na,
          value1 = value[idx],   date1 = date[idx],
          value2 = value[idx1], date2=date[idx1],
          idx = NULL,idx1 = NULL,val_na = NULL
  ) 

# A tibble: 9 x 8
# Groups:   id [1]
     id date        type value value1 date1      value2 date2     
  <dbl> <date>     <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <date>      <dbl> <date>    
1     1 2020-01-01     1    NA      6 2020-03-03      8 2020-04-02
2     1 2020-02-01     1    NA      6 2020-03-03      8 2020-04-02
3     1 2020-03-03     1     6     NA NA             NA NA        
4     1 2020-04-02    NA     8     NA NA             NA NA        
5     1 2020-05-09     1    15     NA NA             NA NA        
6     1 2020-06-10     1    NA      5 2020-07-18      9 2020-08-23
7     1 2020-07-18    NA     5     NA NA             NA NA        
8     1 2020-08-23    NA     9     NA NA             NA NA        
9     1 2020-09-09     1    NA     NA NA             NA NA
```

Comment: Why is row 1 for date1 down having a date? VALUE is NOT NA so we do not need to have a number. For the second row value is NA so we need a fate, for 3:4 value is not NA so we do not need a date, for 5:6 value is NA so we need a date, My question is for row 1 why do we have the date?

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, maybe this is slightly different from the looking upwards. Over here as long as TYPE is NOT NA then we should find the 4 onedown, twodown values.
In the upwards question previously, if TYPE is NOT NA and VALUE is NOT NA I will take that row's data (I did not include this in the upwards example because I can fix this myself after using your suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

```
dtihave %>%
  mutate( value = replace(value, 1, NA),
    val_na = !is.na(value), idx=na_if(val_na * row_number(), 0),
    idx = nafill(idx, 'nocb'), idx = idx * NA^val_na,
    idx1 = row_number() *na_if(val_na & lag(val_na), 0),
    idx1 = nafill(idx1, 'nocb') * NA ^val_na,
    value1 = value[idx],   date1 = date[idx],
    value2 = value[idx1], date2=date[idx1],
    idx = NULL,idx1 = NULL,val_na = NULL
    ) 
        date type value value1      date1 value2      date2
1: 2020-01-01    1    NA      6 2020-03-03      8 2020-04-02
2: 2020-02-01    1    NA      6 2020-03-03      8 2020-04-02
3: 2020-03-03   NA     6     NA       <NA>     NA       <NA>
4: 2020-04-02   NA     8     NA       <NA>     NA       <NA>
5: 2020-05-09    1    NA      5 2020-07-18      9 2020-08-23
6: 2020-06-10    1    NA      5 2020-07-18      9 2020-08-23
7: 2020-07-18   NA     5     NA       <NA>     NA       <NA>
8: 2020-08-23   NA     9     NA       <NA>     NA       <NA>
9: 2020-09-09    1    NA     NA       <NA>     NA       <NA>
```

Comment: Hi onyambu, thank you I have figured the grouping out here as well. But there is a problem: when the TYPE and VALUE are both NOT NA, the code stops working, and so the remaining TYPE NOT NA are not filled. I guess this is because the first mutate line only looks for !is.na(value)? Is there a way around this?

Comment: @JantjeHouten I did not take type into account. I only looked at value

Comment: Hi onyambu, I have edited the question to squeeze in cases where VALUE is also NOT NA. Really appreciate your expertise on this.